# Cygwin-x dbus-daemon process does not unload itself from memory after termination

Tags: windows, memory, cygwin, process, cygwin-x

I have 64 bit cygwin on Windows 10. When I terminate X sessions, a process spawned by `c:\cygwin64\bin\dbus-daemon.exe` stays in memory together with `c:\windows\system32\conhost.exe 0x4`. If I do it several times, new instances of it appear, as many as the sessions I opened and closed. These stay in memory until I restart the whole system.

Not that it is interfering with anything, just sits in memory doing nothing, but still it is clearly some anomaly. Is this known behaviour? What would you advise to do? How can I get rid of it? Of course I can just kill the process manually but...

Not sure if this is related, but almost always this is accompanied by a file `at-spi-bus-launcher.exe.stackdump` created in the cygwin64 root folder.

Comment: I suspect you would get a better response posting to the correct [Cygwin Mailing Lists](https://www.cygwin.com/lists.html). That would be https://www.cygwin.com/mailman/listinfo/cygwin/

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin actually possesses (at least) four versions of emacs, represented by the files emacs-lucid, emacs-X11, emacs-nox and emacs-w32. I just switched to emacs-w32 and the problem is gone. However the others should also work without problems...